# Determine if Hazelcast Node Owns Map Entry

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am running Hazelcast on a 4-node cluster and specifically need to intercept session expiration events to audit an event and a few other cleanup tasks. Since these tasks only need to execute a single time, I attempted to attach a `MapListener<String, ExpiringSession>` as a local map listener to the session `IMap`. This did not meet my needs.

I'm now attempting to create a map interceptor, but find myself needing to "fake" the what a local map listener does by only running certain code on the Hazelcast node that owns that particular session entry.

Below is a mockup of the code.

```
    @Override
    public Object interceptRemove(Object removedValue) {

        // ApplicationSession implements ExpiringSession and also contains the session id
        ApplicationSession session = (ApplicationSession) removedValue;
        // Can I see if the current node actually owns the removed value?

        // if the session is expired, we need to do a session logout audit
        if (session.isExpired()) {
            // do the logout event audit
        }

        // perform other tasks
        return removedValue;
    }
```

So my question is, how do I know which Hazelcast node "owns" the ExpiringSession, since it could be any of the 4 nodes? I get that this seems to be a roundabout way to do this, but again, doing this as a local listener did not meet my needs (due to some other issues with the application that I don't want to get into).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fully worked out solution for this, but I think you might use something like the following approach.

Given the key of your map entry,

```
  Partition partition = hazelcastInstance.getPartitionService().getPartition(key);
```

Which will give you a reference to the Partition that the entry belongs to.  This value should be constant for the life of the cluster (and will only change if the cluster partition count is changed).

You can then see whether the partition is local by calling

```
boolean isLocal = partition.getOwner().localMember();
```

The partition owner will change if cluster membership changes, so you may want to check PartitionService.isClusterSafe() before doing the second part of this, and even then it's possible that the state could change after your check.